# Where the Android apps data stored in Mac which are created using Titanium

Tags: android, android-emulator, location, titanium-mobile

I am using `Titanium` framework for creating Android apps in Mac OSX. I am searching for the location of android apps which are created using Titanium.

We can see our `iPad` or `iPhone` apps based on the `iOS version` . Its location is its iOS version folder. But I am unable to find android apps location.

I have googled for it but no help.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean the build folder? Or do you mean apps in emulator? Apps in Emulator are stored in an "virtual disk image" which is containing the whole emulator software.

Comment: @mr.VVoo Yes I mean `apps in emulator`. Can you tell me where can I find `"virtual disk image" which is containing the whole emulator software` in Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually they are saved in your user profile. `~/.android/avd` is a typical location. It is also possible that they are located within the SDK's directory. This could happen if you set `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` as environment variable.

**To access the file system of android emulator** you have two possibilities:

1. Use the SDK [Device Monitor](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monitor.html). It provides a graphical interface to the file system of the emulator. If you have android SDK in your PATH environment you can access it via Terminal -> `monitor`.
2. Alternatively you can access the file system via command line shell: Terminal -> `adb -e shell`. You already have root access.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Woo I can open monitor window, but it doesn't show any emulator list in it to open its content. I have 5 avd in my system but not showing in monitor list.

Comment: You need to start the emulator. Did you? Otherwise they aren't loaded.

Answer (score 5):

if you run on Mac, open the AVD manager. Clicked the arrow and then "Show on Disk"(...)
[image]